# Dom parser concurrent acces safe? Java

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety, saxparser, domparser

I wanted to ask if reading an XML document withthe DOM parser is thread safe? So multiple threads can read an XML at the same time using the DOM parser or could there happen some sort of access problems when one threads reads the xml and another also wants to read the same xml at the same time?

If DOM parser is not thread safe, maybe the SAX parser is thread safe?